# The transition from "fetching" to "displaying" JSON API data Swift Node.js

Tags: json, swift, api, url

I understand how to "fetch" data from a JSON API (my local server, in fact), but how should I think about the pipeline from merely having the data to displaying it in views? What I intuitively want to do is "return" the data from the fetching function, though I know that's not the paradigm that the Swift URL functions operate with. My thought is that if I can "return" the data (as a struct) it will be easy to pass into a view for visualization.

Sample Code:

This is the structure of the fetched JSON and the kind of variable I want to pass into views.

```
struct User: Codable {
    let userID: String
    let userName: String
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let fullName: String
}
```

My hope is that the printUser function can return instead of print a successful fetch.

```
func printUser() {
    fetchUser { (res) in
        switch res {
        case .success(let user):
            print(user.userName) // return here? 
                              // I know it won't work, but that's what seems natural
        case .failure(let err):
            print("Failed to fetch user: ", err)
        }
    }
}

func fetchUser(completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> ()) {
    let urlString = "http://localhost:4001/user"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in
    
        if let err = err {
            completion(.failure(err))
            return
        }
    
        do {
            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data!)
            completion(.success(user))
        
        } catch let jsonError {
            completion(.failure(jsonError))
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Sample view that would take a user struct

```
struct DisplayUser: View {
    var user: User
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.userID)
        Text(user.userName)
        Text(user.lastName)
        Text(user.firstName)
        Text(user.fullName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can't just "return" is that your `fetchUser` is *asynchronous*. That means that it *might* return relatively instantaneously or it may take a long time (or not finish at all). So, your program needs to be prepared to deal with that eventuality. Sure, it would be "be easy to pass into a view for visualization" as you put it, but unfortunately, it just doesn't fit the reality of the situation.

What you can do (in your example) is set the `User` as an Optional -- that way, if it hasn't been set, you can display some sort of loading view and if it *has* been set (ie your async function has returned a value), you can display it. That would look something like this:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
  @Published var user : User? //could optionally store the entire Result here

  func runFetch() {
    fetchUser { (res) in
        switch res {
        case .success(let user):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.user = user
            }
        case .failure(let err):
            print("Failed to fetch user: ", err)
            //set an error message here? Another @Published variable?
        }
    }
  }

  func fetchUser(completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> ()) {
    //...
  }
}

struct DisplayUser: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          if let user = viewModel.user {
            Text(user.userID)
            Text(user.userName)
            Text(user.lastName)
            Text(user.firstName)
            Text(user.fullName)
          } else {
             Text("Loading...")
          }
        }.onAppear {
          viewModel.fetchUser()
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I'd probably refactor the async stuff to use Combine if this were my program, but it's a personal preference issue*

Comment: I appreciate your answer--and the many other of my questions that you've answered. Stack Overflow overall has been incredibly helpful, but you deserve personal recognition.